# How to cancel file open prompt window using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE.

I need to be able to click **Cancel** button of a browser popup, which asks to Save or Open a file.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to do this with the IDE. The popup is outside of control by the IDE, sorry.